# Как отследить нажатие на "Рассказать друзьям"?

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте! Как отследить нажатие на "Рассказать друзьям" в виджете "Мне нравится", расположенном на сайте?

Подписка:

```
VK.Observer.subscribe('widgets.like.liked',function());
```

Помогает только при нажатии именно на виджет "Мне нравится", если же я навожу мышь на виджет, а потом нажимаю на "Рассказать друзьям" в всплывающем окошке, то ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1):

"Рассказать друзьям" это другое событие

```
VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.shared", function f() {
   //код ...................
});
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?